# Ant to add workspace folder in classpath as a dependent project

Tags: ant

I have one Ant project say **xyz**, I want, when I put this project to one random workspace,  and when I build xyz then it would automatically add workspace folder config (already present in workspace) and task (already present in workspace) to their classpath as dependent project.

Comment: What kind of projects are supposed to be into the workspace? Ant projects?

Comment: What are those _folder config_ and _task_?

Comment: The other folders i.e. projects are ANT projects.

Comment: Here are the links of my build.xml for both project, kindly look on this :

1. xyz project - xyz_build.xml - https://www.dropbox.com/s/rf7ezl5y4slpfs3/xyz_build.xml?dl=0
2. config project - config_build.xml - https://www.dropbox.com/s/nrn158stch4cm6a/config_build.xml?dl=0

Comment: I've read both projects but I don't understand how they would be related.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if all the projects in the workspace follow the same standard about the classfile folder, let's say `project/build`:

```
project1/
    build/
       class files...
project2/
    build/
       class files...
project3/
    build/
       class files...
xyz/
    build.xml
```

.. you could set the classpath in `xyz/build.xml` like this:

```
<project basedir=".">
    <path id="my.classpath">
        <dirset dir=".." includes="**/build"/>
    </path>
    <javac classpathref="my.classpath">
        ...
    </javac>
</project>
```

In this way, all of the .class files previously produced in every project else in the workspace will be included in the compilation of xyz.

In case you know exactly what projects you want to include in xyz's classpath, you have to set it like this:

```
<project basedir=".">
    <path id="my.classpath">
        <pathelement location="../project1/build"/>
        <pathelement location="../project2/build"/>
    </path>
    <javac classpathref="my.classpath">
        ...
    </javac>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my concern is that, I just want to add project1 and project2 in project xyz classpath. Also workspace other project doesn't follow same standard

Comment: No I am not getting, can you please share ur skype or gmail id, so that I can send you build.xml of both the project.

Comment: No, sorry. You'd better post your scripts into your question.